# Simplifying the solution of differential equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, equation, simplify

I tried various methods to simplify the solution to the following differential equation, but was unable to fully simplify it to 0.01e^(-0.15t)sin(9.999t+1.556) and expressions with radicals were not properly simplified either. Can someone please explain how the solution can be fully simplified with the number of terms reduced as much as possible?

```
syms y(t) m k x c 

Dy = diff(y,t);
Dy2 = diff(y,t,2);  
m = 10; c = 3; k = 1000; 
ode = m*Dy2 +c*Dy + k*y == 0;
eqns = [ode]
cond = [y(0) == 0.01,Dy(0) == 0];
ySol(t) = dsolve(eqns,cond)
ySol(t) = simplify(ySol(t),'steps',500)
pretty(ySol(t)) 
vpa(ySol(t), 5)
simplify(ySol(t))
```

Comment: Are you sure that the desired form is really a solution? What is the code currently producing? Maybe plot the current and the expected results for some t to show that indeed Matlab is not simplifying enough.

Comment: Yes, it is a simplified form of Matlab's output. The solution Matlab contains a term of the form a*cos(b) + c*sin(d), and this can be simplified to a single cosine or sine function.

Answer (score 0):

Pass output of `vpa` function into `simplify` function, as follows:

```
vpa(simplify(vpa(ySol(t), 3)),3)
```